# Firebase and React JS Authentication

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to design a web page in which User can register via phone number, OTP Received and password set by user and then login with that phone number and password in future. How can i implement this feature in firebase as backend and React JS as Frontend.

i tried using firebase but there is only login method via email and Password, there is no method for phone number and password login available.